# How to query for User Display Name using LisData.svc SharePoint Online

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssis, ssms, reporting

As you know when using the listdata.svc people picker fields return the userID, not the display name (createdby, modifiedby). I have been looking for a way to query the userprofile svc but have found nothing helpful.

What i am looking to do, is simply convert this ID to their respected display name. I am new to using this listsvc and this was never and issue using empty data views and XSL. If anyone has an example of grabbing list data, and showing the createdby, modifiedby, or a custom people picker field and showing their name not id that would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is a *default* behavior, for a user field,  only `Id` property is getting returned in the result. To return all the properties of user field [`$expand` query options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd541606.aspx) needs to be applied to the query, for example:

```
/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Documents?$expand=CreatedBy,ModifiedBy
```

In that case the projected field values for  `CreatedBy`and `ModifiedBy` fields (from `User Information List`) are returned along with the result.

To return a *specific* user field properties, the [`$select` query option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee525214.aspx) could be specified. For example, the following query returns `DisplayName` (`Title` property) of `CreatedBy` and `ModifiedBy` fields:

```
/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Documents?$select=CreatedBy/Title,ModifiedBy/Title&$expand=CreatedBy,ModifiedBy
```

Comment: Hi Vadim. Thanks for the response. I tried this option previously but it wouldnt work. I had to work around it by doing a join with between both tables via a reporting tool